# How do I update a JavaScript generated widget with KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, vis.js

I have one of these timeline widgets:
http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/interaction/eventListeners.html

The source data looks like this:

```
var items = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2013-04-20'},
  {id: 2, content: 'item 2', start: '2013-04-14'},
  {id: 3, content: 'item 3', start: '2013-04-18'},
  {id: 4, content: 'item 4', start: '2013-04-16', end: '2013-04-19'},
  {id: 5, content: 'item 5', start: '2013-04-25'},
  {id: 6, content: 'item 6', start: '2013-04-27'}
]);
```

How do I update like something like this when I'm using Knockout for the rest of the elements on the page?

Should I ignore Knockout and just update the array with Javascript when the json is received?

Like this:

```
function viewModel() {

    this.price = ko.observable(0);

    this.loadViewModel = function() {
        $.getJSON('/pagedata', function(data) {

            updateTimeline(data.timeline);

            /* update rest of view model */
            this.price(data.price);
        });

    }
}
```

Or is there a more sensible way to do it.

Comment: Hi there. We try to discourage commentary about voting here, at least in posts themselves - you can add a comment if you really want to. The reason for this is that readers outnumber voters by a wide margin, and thus remarks of this nature are not relevant for most readers. In my experience, they do no have any effect anyway - people will vote how they wish.

Comment: Any ideas why this post was downvoted so heavily?

Comment: No, none at all. Voting is anonymous by design, and the only restriction is that one may not vote serially on one person. It is helpful if people explain their downvotes, but they are not obliged to, and will already have moved on by the time you comment.

Comment: Did you get the votes on your first version? It was a bit brief, though not in my view worth a downvote. Perhaps people were looking for what you had tried to solve the problem (which you've now added). Anyway, don't worry about it - you can always answer a few questions if you'd like to bump your score up!

Answer (score -1):

Knockout is for connecting a model to a view. The timeline widget has such a connection built-in -- you update the data and the view updates accordingly, right? -- so you have no reason that I can see to bring knockout into it.

Comment: The timeline is part of the view. I think there should be one view model. The timeline data should therefore be included in the view model knockout uses but it doesn't have to be processed by knockout. Is that correct?